# Ecto embedded schema cache?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am working on a large production app, we use an embedded_schema to both store and display some user configs on the User record and in the view/template.  I recently changed the embedded_schema removing a field, built the app, and deployed to production.

Two days later if I run a query on any user the field is no longer showing up in the JSONB column; however, in the application, it continues to show up for all users until the page is refreshed.

Our application does use Redis for some jobs but no caching dependencies from what I can tell looking at the mix files.  Is there something out of the box in Phoenix or Ecto that would be causing this to happen?

Comment: Deployed again and it's gone now.

Comment: For the record, the issue was that one server had not been properly deployed which was causing issues the load balancer was giving the appearance that some records were updated and others were not.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the issue was that one server had not been properly deployed which was causing issues the load balancer was giving the appearance that some records were updated and others were not.

-Answering so this question doesn't show up as unanswered and as a reminder to always check your deploys ;)